# What is the purpose of the _HACK methods in System.Internal (.net 4.0 on x64)

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, 64-bit, internals

In the mscorlib of .net 4.0 on x64 there is a class `System.Internal` that contains three static methods with the suffix `_HACK`. Does anybody have an idea what the purpose of these methods is?

Here is the .NET Reflector output:

```
internal static class Internal
{
    // Methods
    private static void CommonlyUsedGenericInstantiations_HACK()
    {
        Array.Sort<double>(null);
        Array.Sort<int>(null);
        Array.Sort<IntPtr>(null);
        new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1], 0, 0);
        new Dictionary<char, object>();
        new Dictionary<Guid, byte>();
        new Dictionary<Guid, object>();
        new Dictionary<Guid, Guid>();
        new Dictionary<short, IntPtr>();
        new Dictionary<int, byte>();
        new Dictionary<int, int>();
        new Dictionary<int, object>();
        new Dictionary<IntPtr, bool>();
        new Dictionary<IntPtr, short>();
        new Dictionary<object, bool>();
        new Dictionary<object, char>();
        new Dictionary<object, Guid>();
        new Dictionary<object, int>();
        new Dictionary<object, long>();
        new Dictionary<uint, WeakReference>();
        new Dictionary<object, uint>();
        new Dictionary<uint, object>();
        new Dictionary<long, object>();
        new Dictionary<MemberTypes, object>();
        new EnumEqualityComparer<MemberTypes>();
        new Dictionary<object, KeyValuePair<object, object>>();
        new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<object, object>, object>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<bool>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<byte>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<char>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<DateTime>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<decimal>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<double>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<Guid>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<short>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<int>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<long>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<float>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<TimeSpan>();
        NullableHelper_HACK<DateTimeOffset>();
        new List<bool>();
        new List<byte>();
        new List<char>();
        new List<DateTime>();
        new List<decimal>();
        new List<double>();
        new List<Guid>();
        new List<short>();
        new List<int>();
        new List<long>();
        new List<TimeSpan>();
        new List<sbyte>();
        new List<float>();
        new List<ushort>();
        new List<uint>();
        new List<ulong>();
        new List<IntPtr>();
        new List<KeyValuePair<object, object>>();
        new List<GCHandle>();
        new List<DateTimeOffset>();
        RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.Prejitinit_HACK();
        new CerArrayList<RuntimeMethodInfo>(0);
        new CerArrayList<RuntimeConstructorInfo>(0);
        new CerArrayList<RuntimePropertyInfo>(0);
        new CerArrayList<RuntimeEventInfo>(0);
        new CerArrayList<RuntimeFieldInfo>(0);
        new CerArrayList<RuntimeType>(0);
        new KeyValuePair<char, ushort>('\0', 0);
        new KeyValuePair<ushort, double>(0, double.MinValue);
        new KeyValuePair<object, int>(string.Empty, -2147483648);
        new KeyValuePair<int, int>(-2147483648, -2147483648);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<bool>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<byte>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<DateTime>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<decimal>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<double>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<Guid>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<short>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<int>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<long>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<TimeSpan>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<sbyte>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<float>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<ushort>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<uint>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<ulong>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<DateTimeOffset>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<CustomAttributeTypedArgument>(null);
        SZArrayHelper_HACK<CustomAttributeNamedArgument>(null);
    }

    private static T NullableHelper_HACK<T>() where T: struct
    {
        Nullable.Compare<T>(null, null);
        Nullable.Equals<T>(null, null);
        T? nullable = null;
        return nullable.GetValueOrDefault();
    }

    private static void SZArrayHelper_HACK<T>(SZArrayHelper oSZArrayHelper)
    {
        oSZArrayHelper.get_Count<T>();
        oSZArrayHelper.get_Item<T>(0);
        oSZArrayHelper.GetEnumerator<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's covered but add my own interpretation.  It is a code generation optimization.  When the jitter generates code for a generic class, it only needs to generate a few versions of it.  There's one that covers any reference type, that's why you see *object* being used in the code.  And there's one each for each distinct value type.  That's why you see byte, bool, short, int, uint being popular.

This code lives in mscorlib.dll and is therefore available precompiled in the ngen-ed image.  Which the jitter can then directly use without a need to generate the machine code on-the-fly.  In effect, it is a workaround for ngen being incapable of guessing up front which generic instantiations will be required.   Clearly it isn't practical to exhaustively pregen every possible combination, especially for a class like Dictionary<>.  They no doubt analyzed a bunch of code to see what generic type arguments were most popular, probably starting with the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be making sure those functions and objects have been instantiated (according to @usr, it is NGEN that would be doing those instantiations).  That technique is also common in C++ to ensure that particular template instantiations are compiled into a library.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremiah Willcock is not entirely correct: This is not targeted at the JIT but at the NGEN compiler. It creates a mostly-static native dll from the managed dll. The JIT does not care about these instantiations.

Comment: So it is more like the C++ version than I thought.  I had assumed it was to force the JIT to instantiate things since that is usually how generics are instantiated.

Comment: I think you could say that. Did not notice the similarity.